# What are some good approaches for initializing a Scylladb database with docker compose?

Tags: nosql, micronaut, scylla

I have a micronaut app that starts up with a Scylla database and I want initialize a keyspace and a columnfamily so that people can run the app locally and have it ready to use.

For my initial approach I created a singleton cqlSession and then I create those things there.

```
@Singleton
public CqlSession cqlSession(ScyllaConfig scyllaConfig) throws UnknownHostException
{
    CqlSessionBuilder sessionBuilder = CqlSession.builder()
            .addContactPoints(scyllaConfig.contactPoints().stream().map(host -> new InetSocketAddress(host, scyllaConfig.port())).toList())
            .withLocalDatacenter(scyllaConfig.datacenter());

    CqlSession session =  sessionBuilder.build();
    session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS " + scyllaConfig.keyspaceName() + " WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};");
    session.execute("CREATE COLUMNFAMILY IF NOT EXISTS " + scyllaConfig.keyspaceName() + ".payment_data (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, account_id int, person_id int, payment_id text);");
    return session;
}
```

This doesn't seem like the best approach. I was hoping there would be someway to plugging a cql file or something like that where I could run a bunch of cql and initialize the database, but I can't find anything on how to do that. If worse comes to worse, I could just right a bash script or something like that. Would I just call that from a docker compose file? Is there a better way?

What approaches have you taken? This seems like a common use case so I wanted to get thoughts on best approaches for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the best way to find answers about scylladb is to ask you search for answers to Cassandra. A good answer is found here: [Init script for Cassandra with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443617/init-script-for-cassandra-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for something equivalent to putting schema scripts in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory that is available on MySql images. Turns out that works on some cassandra images like `bitnami/cassandra` but doesn't work on the standard scylla image.

I took inspiration from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443617/init-script-for-cassandra-with-docker-compose) but it didn't work out of the box for scylla so I figured I'd share what I had to do to get it working here:

The easiest way I have found is to create two containers. The first container will spin up the blank scylla db; the second container will populate the db in th first container. The blank db will take some time to initialize and be ready for `cqlsh` connections so we feed the second container an initialization script that runs a while loop to check and see if it can connect to the first container with `cqlsh`. Once it can connect, it executes the `.cql` files to create the schema and populate the db.

How my local directory is structured:

```
/app
   |_docker_compose.yml
   |_scylla_scripts
         |_create_schema.cql
         |_populate_db.cql
         |_initdb.sh
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  scylla:
    image: scylladb/scylla
    container_name: scylla
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  # This is a temporary service that creates the schema and populates the scylla service and then this one shuts down
  scylla-load-keyspace:
    container_name: scylla-load-keyspace
    image: scylladb/scylla
    volumes:
      - ./scylla_scripts/create_schema.cql:/scylla_scripts/1.cql
      - ./scylla_scripts/populate_db.cql:/scylla_scripts/2.cql
      - ./scylla_scripts/initdb.sh:/scylla_scripts/initdb.sh
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "/scylla_scripts/initdb.sh" ]
```

create_schema.cql:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE employee_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

USE employee_keyspace;

CREATE TABLE employee_keyspace.employee (
     employee_id int PRIMARY KEY,
     email text,
     first_name text,
     last_name text
    );
```

populate_db.cql:

```
INSERT INTO employee_keyspace.employee JSON '{ "employee_id": 12345, "email": "johndoe@example.com", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe" }';
INSERT INTO employee_keyspace.employee JSON '{ "employee_id": 12346, "email": "janedoe@example.com", "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe" }';
```

initdb.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "######### Starting to execute SH script... #########"

# If you have credentials for your DB uncomment the following two lines
#USER_NAME='user_name'
#PASSWORD='user_password'

echo "######### Sleeping for 25 seconds #########"
sleep 25

# If you have credentials for your DB use: while ! cqlsh scylla -u "${USER_NAME}" -p "${PASSWORD}" -e 'describe cluster' ; do
while ! cqlsh scylla -e 'describe cluster' ; do
     echo "######### Waiting for main instance to be ready... #########"
     sleep 5
done

for cql_file in ./scylla_scripts/*.cql;
do
# If you have credentials on your db use this line cqlsh scylla -u "${USER_NAME}" -p "${PASSWORD}" -f "${cql_file}" ;
  cqlsh scylla -f "${cql_file}" ;
  echo "######### Script ""${cql_file}"" executed!!! #########"
done
echo "######### Execution of SH script is finished! #########"
echo "######### Stopping temporary instance! #########"
```